# local match kickoff time

Tags: php, javascript

I'm working on a sports website and need to convert the server's match start time to local match start time.

After much googling, I figured the fastest and most accurate way is to get the GMT offset value in JavaScript. The trouble is, I can't pass the GMT offset value to PHP. I've tried using both the PHP session and cookie variables, but both are always empty. The website doesn't require a user account, so there isn't any stored GMT value in the database.

I'm trying to auto-detect each user's local timezone every time he/she visits the website, and then calculate the local match start time based on the timezone offset. Can someone please advise me? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this server side? Why not use pure JavaScript to change a start time you set in a JavaScript variable using PHP?

Comment: The match details are all generated using php. So I thought the most straight forward way is to get the gmt offset value in javascript and passing it to php to do the local time calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

Get the match start time (as stored on the server), in your Javascript function and apply the timezone offset in the function itself.

OR,

Pass the local timezone as a GET value in a AJAX request to your PHP script, where the offset can be applied to the server match start time and the new time passed back to javascript as the request response

Comment: The first method sounds easier. But won't the users the time change suddenly in front of their eyes? eg. 4.30am suddenly change to 11.30am

Comment: Doesn't have to be that way. The html tag supposed to show the time can have a value of 'calculating time...'. Once your javascript function has calculated the local time, use .innerHTML() to change 'calculating time...' to the time calculated